# Put delay on a particular image / loop it , while merging several gifs using convert (Imagemagick)

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, gif, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to merge several gif images using `convert` of `imagemagick`. Each image has its own position and size. 
Suppose

> img1.gif is having 8 frames
>
> img2.gif is having 2 frames

In the resultant image,

> img2.gif becomes invisible after 2 frames

Once 8 frames of img1.gif is animated again img2.gif comes for only 2 frames.

Here is my convert query:

```
convert backgroung.jpg -coalesce \
       -delete 1 \
       null:  \( img1.gif -coalesce -resize 322x360 \) \
       -gravity Center -geometry -14-34 -loop 0 -layers composite null: \( img2.gif -coalesce -resize 171x126 \) \
       -gravity Center -geometry -289-210 -loop 0 -layers composite null:  \
       -set -delay 20 -loop 0 -layers optimize resultImg.gif
```

Example gifs 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9xc4.jpg  2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8yw2.jpg  Result gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N17Wu.jpg

Comment: Can you provide example gifs for us to work with?

Comment: Examples : 
1. http://imgur.com/wDB8ulU
2. http://imgur.com/oi95RXx